# Play age of empires III on ubuntu 16.04 LTE

Tags: wine

I ran Age of Empires on wine and installed it correctly but it didn't fit my screen size. What should I change to get it work?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Can you clarify what you mean by 'it didn't fit my screen size', e.g. by posting a screenshot?

Comment: well I wanted to get one but I couldn't because it blocked my laptop and had to turn it of. I tried to fix it myself but it wasn't possible :/

Comment: Isn't there a resolution setting in AOE itself? It's usually under Options.